# Animate toolbar background colour when scrolled down

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a fixed tool bar with a dark background colour on top of my page with the following code.

[image: toolbar]

```
/*html*/
<div class="floating-header-div">
    <md-toolbar>
        <a>Login</a>
    </md-toolbar>
</div>

/*css*/
.floating-header-div {
    position: fixed;  
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;  
}

md-toolbar {
    background-color : rgb(55,58,60);
}
```

What I want to achieve is that the tool bar starts off with transparent background colour when the page is not scrolled. (So I only see the login link)

As the user scroll down abit more (past a certain section), the background color of the toolbar appears. Preferably animated.

How can I achieve this. I am using Angular 2 so preferably nothing too fancy like using document or jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(scroll)="onScroll($event)` to catch the scroll event and with `@ViewChild` access the toolbar. With a simple validation toogle when your toolbar has to be transparent:

```
<div #content class="content">

    <md-toolbar class="toolbar" color="{{ setColor ? 'primary' : 'accent' }}">
        <span>Login</span>
    </md-toolbar>

    <div class="topimage"></div>

    <p>Content</p>
</div>

@ViewChild('content') content;
setColor = false;

onScroll(event) {
    this.setColor = this.content.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top < -64;
}
```

I am not very good with Angular 2 animations but you can do it with CSS3:

```
.mat-toolbar{
  -webkit-transition: background-color 400ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 400ms linear;
    transition: background-color 400ms linear;
}
```

Here is a working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/emKv4YXGEGiRj8lyaWgr?p=preview

Comment: Great solution. Thanks. I also found this solution from this website if you or anyone are interested. http://www.route2it.com/uncategorized/creating-an-animated-header-with-angular-2/

Answer (score 0):

this should help you, you may need to modify this to suit your needs.

```
/*for setting navigation bar colour*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scroll_start = 0;
    var nav_element = $(".navbar");
    var startchange = $('#my_element'); // element to start change when it reaches the top

    var nav_element_height = nav_element.outerHeight();
    var startchange_offset = startchange.offset().top;

    var offset = Math.round(startchange_offset - nav_element_height);

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(scroll_start > offset) {
            nav_element.addClass('navbar-bg-color');
        } else {
            nav_element.removeClass('navbar-bg-color');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think using document and $ in angular 2 is not recommended though

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :)

```js
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
             if (this.pageYOffset >= 50) {
                 scope.boolChangeClass = true;
             } else {
                 scope.boolChangeClass = false;
             }
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; background: lightgrey; min-height: 900px;}

.header {
  background: transparent;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 24px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 150;
  font: 18px sans-serif;
  color: white;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
}

.min .header { height: 50px; padding: 14px 24px; background: rgb(55,58,60);}
img{
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title> 
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" scroll id="page" ng-class="{min:boolChangeClass}">
    <div class="header">Header Title</div>
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/115045/pexels-photo-115045.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb">
      
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks sweet. But I think using document and $ in angular 2 is not recommended though